# R: burnin.phybreak - Error in if (runif(1) < exp(logaccprob))

Tags: r, mcmc, phylogeny, transmission

I'm trying to use the *burnin.phybreak* function to run an MCMC-chain however, I keep getting the following error message and have no idea how to proceed;

**Error in if (runif(1) < exp(logaccprob)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

I have managed to make the phybreak object as shown in the CRAN, and the chain works on one of my datasets but none of the other.

I know this is very little information to work off, but I don't know what else to do and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And what do you get if you type `logaccprob` into the console?

Comment: @AllanCameron it gives me the following error; "Error: object 'logaccprob' not found"